# how to render visible armature

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, shaders

**IN BLENDER 2.79b**

how can I render a render where the armature is visible and the mesh is hidden
[Armature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTApT.png)

[image: My armature screenshot]
[image]

Comment: far as I understand power is due, but still can not find anyone who knows how.

Comment: i do it, I will not publish the solution because they gave me negative votes to my question and it is as valid as anyone's, i do, render bones is possible with shading language

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you will not help the whole community because one person gave you a negative vote on your question? That's a quite petty reaction.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The armature isn't a mesh or considered as a 'real' 3D object in Blender. It's a visual aide for positioning your mesh, nothing else. Thus why it cannot be rendered.

As said in the [Blender Manual](https://easyblend.org/html/rigging/armatures/visualization.html#armature-layers)

> These shapes will never be rendered - like any bone, they are only visible in 3D Views.

Comment: should be able to do, because what you're looking at is an OPENGL render made with blender

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/osh0ofI.png

Comment: what you wrote is not an answer, it sounds more like a simple comment you should remove it

Comment: @BlenderBlackened I updated my answer with a quote from the Blender Manual. Though, I tested the OpenGL on my computer and it seems to work, so, why don't you use it?

Comment: your answer is still a simple comment because the reference is wrong

Comment: I want a Final Render, where the model and the armor appear, I do not want to move bones between ca'paz, it is to hide or appear parts of the model or the armor, it is something that any novice must learn from the beginning

Comment: That is not what you ask in your question: 'how can I render a render where the _**armature is visible** and the **mesh is hidden.**_' My answer still stands: there is no way to do that natively because bones are for rigging and were never intended to be rendered in the first place. You may have to look around for possible add-ons or script that allow you to do that.

Comment: See this question and it's answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18645/is-it-possible-to-render-an-armature?rq=1 No idea if the script will work with 2.79 since it was made for 2.72 and there has been changes since then in the code. And it is to be noted that the script sort of cheats by creating real mesh that can be rendered attached to the bones. Again, bones themselves were never meant to be rendered in the first place.

Comment: no, addon only creates a mesh based on the bones, as if it were the skin modifier, I'm not interested in having raytrace, and I think that this is more inclined to solve it within the source code of blender, the problem is that here asking this is a bigger problem, it offends them to ask about source code things, their vision is limited and obtuse, and if I ask in blender org they do not answer almost anything or just ignore you and tell you that you see it in this place or in a forum.

Comment: i do it, I will not publish the solution because they gave me negative votes to my question and it is as valid as anyone's, i do, render bones is possible with shading language