# does the armature_to_mesh add-on work in blender 2.8?

Tags: armature, add-on

the add-on is discussed here
[Is it possible to render an armature?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18645/is-it-possible-to-render-an-armature)

best,
Mathias

Comment: Hi. Isn't this something you could very easily try? Have you tried it and experienced problems?

Comment: you are right, i see now that it says "upgrade to 2.8 required" when i find it under my add-on preferences. - apparently thats a simple message saying "the addon's bl_info version in init.py is not set to (2, 80, 0)" I tried adding it to the python script as explained in this forum: 
https://github.com/MadMinstrel/blender-sculpt-tools/issues/9.

which allowed me to run the script, but it still doesn't work. I think any further changes to the script is out of my skillset right now.