# bvh display multiple frames at the same time

Tags: bvh

[image]

How to display multiple frames of a BVH file at the same time？Then can I get a picture like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Onion Skinning.**

*My very first attempt at an addon for blender was a thing called "Mocap Madness". I thought for a while blender had the possibility to display onion skinned armatures, or maybe I coded similar to this, and recall that.*

[image]

*Only had CMU 01_01 floating around, result of running script below*

- Push the bvh action down into the NLA editor

  [image]

  _Example, rig generated from CMU 01_01, action pushed down
- Copy the rig. A linked copy will save a lot of space (same armature data)
- Shift the strip start of the action in the NLA editor.

Here is a test script, the following

```
frame_range = (200, 1000, 100)
```

make a copy starting at frame 200, every 100 frames until frame 1000. Edit to suit.
If the action is the only one pushed down in the NLA can assume it is track zero strip zero.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
scene = context.scene
collection = context.collection

# clean up last run.
obs = [o for o in scene.objects if o.get("Frame", False)]
bpy.data.batch_remove(obs)

tracks = ob.animation_data.nla_tracks[0]
strip = tracks.strips[0]
print(strip.action)
action = strip.action
#frame_range = map(int, action.frame_range)
frame_range = (200, 1000, 100)
for f in range(*frame_range):
    print(f)
    x = ob.copy()
    x.name = f"Frame {f}"
    x["Frame"] = True
    x.animation_data.nla_tracks[0].strips[0].frame_start = -1 * f
    collection.objects.link(x)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I need!