# put color to bvh and render

Tags: bvh

[image]

I imported a BVH file, but I can't find the coloring option. How do I add color to it？

[image]

And what steps do I need to take if I want to get the image above? Do I just set a white background? I'm not sure how to set a pure white background.

I changed the color and rendered but the there is nothing in the image? Why the bones disappeared？
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to render an armature?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18645/is-it-possible-to-render-an-armature) -> *"Blender doesn't support rendering armatures, this is intentional and there is no plan to add support for this feature."*

Comment: In this case prob sufficent to  change the pose bone colors, hide stuff like the grid, via overlay , select all armatures, enter pose mode and render viewport   https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/properties/bone_groups.html#color-set

Comment: I followed this link about bone groups and successfully change the color! Thanks!

Comment: I also tried the Armature to mesh add-on but it didn't work...

Comment: Added an answer to dupe, based on comments above.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos was a bit twixt and between answering dupe or voting to re-open this one. Ended up answering dupe. VP render may be a viable option here, where as dupe q stipulates no VP render.

Comment: @batFINGER Indeed, if it does require shadows, but it is a nice workaround nontheless. Thanks for updating the script on the other answer though, always nasty being pointed to a dupe with code that doesn't work

Comment: @batFINGER  I'm sorry maybe I have a problem with my presentation. (My English is poor... I mean I tried to install this add-on but I can't use it. I'm not familiar with how blender works.